# How to navigate in sublime through keypad keys?

Tags: sublimetext2, sublimetext3, sublimetext

Sublime 'alt+ numeric keys' work to switch between least 10 tabs opened
but same option doesn't work  with keypad keys doesn't work.
does anybody have idea how to make it work?
thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
open preferences  keybinding and add this lines.
and now alt+keypad 0-9 keys work to swtich tabs
```

```
[{ "keys": ["alt+keypad1"], "command": "select_by_index", "args": { "index": 0 } },
{ "keys": ["alt+keypad2"], "command": "select_by_index", "args": { "index": 1 } },
{ "keys": ["alt+keypad3"], "command": "select_by_index", "args": { "index": 2 } },
{ "keys": ["alt+keypad4"], "command": "select_by_index", "args": { "index": 3 } },
{ "keys": ["alt+keypad5"], "command": "select_by_index", "args": { "index": 4 } },
{ "keys": ["alt+keypad6"], "command": "select_by_index", "args": { "index": 5 } },
{ "keys": ["alt+keypad7"], "command": "select_by_index", "args": { "index": 6 } },
{ "keys": ["alt+keypad8"], "command": "select_by_index", "args": { "index": 7 } },
{ "keys": ["alt+keypad9"], "command": "select_by_index", "args": { "index": 8 }}]
```

Answer (score 2):

Just add this to your User keybindings file:

```
{ "keys": ["alt+keypad1"], "command": "select_by_index", "args": { "index": 0 } },
{ "keys": ["alt+keypad2"], "command": "select_by_index", "args": { "index": 1 } },
{ "keys": ["alt+keypad3"], "command": "select_by_index", "args": { "index": 2 } },
{ "keys": ["alt+keypad4"], "command": "select_by_index", "args": { "index": 3 } },
{ "keys": ["alt+keypad5"], "command": "select_by_index", "args": { "index": 4 } },
{ "keys": ["alt+keypad6"], "command": "select_by_index", "args": { "index": 5 } },
{ "keys": ["alt+keypad7"], "command": "select_by_index", "args": { "index": 6 } },
{ "keys": ["alt+keypad8"], "command": "select_by_index", "args": { "index": 7 } },
{ "keys": ["alt+keypad9"], "command": "select_by_index", "args": { "index": 8 } },
{ "keys": ["alt+keypad0"], "command": "select_by_index", "args": { "index": 9 } },
```